# Store IList selected data to a variable

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-builder

I'am working with Adobe AIR application and i have a registration form which contains a combobox which consist of 2 values...i want to store the selected value to a variable..

here is the code..

```
           var a:IList  = new ArrayCollection(['Nurse','Patient']).list;
            selectbox.dataProvider =a;
```

suppose if it was a textbox,we can store the value like this:-

```
var lastname:String = textbox2.text;
```

in the same way how can i store the selected value from combobox...?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll use the `selectedItem` property:

```
var role:String = selectbox.selectedItem;
```

*P.S. Welcome to StackOverflow!  If you find my answer helpful, please be sure to 'accept' it by clicking the green checkmark to the left.*